# Bring focus to selected ListItem programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I am now confused on how to set focus to a selected item of a devexpress `ListBoxEdit`.

I will explain the scenario :
I have a `MainView`. This is the main xaml. When user clicks on a tile, he is navigated to this xaml.
I divided the main view into 2 columns each column containing a view ie `View1` and `View2`.
`View1` consists of a devexpress `ListBoxEdit` and `View2` consists of few textblocks which displays data according to the selected item.

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit x:Name="ListBoxEdit1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    BorderThickness="0"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelectorForListEdit}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem,
                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now I am binding the selected item correctly. My issue is when user navigates to the `MainView`, he sees that a listitem is selected in the `ListBoxEdit`. He tries to press keyboard down key to move the selection down. But he can’t do that since the focus is not set on the `ListBoxEdit`. To move the selection he needs to press the down key 4-5 times after which `ListBoxEdit` attains focus and moves the selection.

I tried `ListBoxEdit.Focus()`, tried to focus the grid in `MainView` as well as grids in `View1`, but it still requires atleast **2 down key presses** to move the selection.

Is there any way to bring focus to the selected item within the ListBoxEdit? 
Any help would be appreciated.